# Whitening Transformation using a Hadamard product Variance Matrix

Tags: time-series, correlation, autocorrelation, covariance-matrix

I want to whiten a vector $X$ by transforming the variance-covariance matrix so the variance-covariance matrix of the transformed series will be the identity matrix $I$.

$X$ is a time-series column vector with variance-covariance matrix $M$ and mean $0$.

If $X$ was a set of correlated data, then the covariance matrix $M$ could be written as the outer product of $X$ with itself: $M=\mathrm{E}\left[XX^T\right]$. $M$ is thus a variance-covariance matrix, symmetric and positive semidefinite, has a square root $M^{{1}/{2}}$, so $M^{{1}/{2}}\left(M^{{1}/{2}}\right)^T=M$.

If $M$ is positive definite then $M^{{1}/{2}}$ is invertible, so the vector $Y=M^{-{1}/{2}}X$ has covariance matrix:

$\mathrm{Cov}\left[Y\right]=\mathrm{E}\left[YY^T\right] = M^{-{1}/{2}}\mathrm{E}\left[XX^T\right]\left( M^{-{1}/{2}}\right)^T=M^{-{1}/{2}}M\left( M^{-{1}/{2}}\right)^T=\left(M^{-{1}/{2}}M^{{1}/{2}}\right)\left(M^{{1}/{2}}\right)^T\left( M^{-{1}/{2}}\right)^T=I$

However, when $X$ is a time series $M$, the variance-covariance matrix is constructed from the autocovariance function of $X$ as:

$\left(\begin{array}{cccc} \gamma\left(0\right) & \gamma\left(1\right) & \cdots & \gamma\left(n-1\right)\\ \gamma\left(1\right) & \gamma\left(0\right) & \cdots & \gamma\left(n-2\right)\\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ \gamma\left(n-1\right) & \gamma\left(n-2\right) & \cdots & \gamma\left(0\right)       \end{array}\right)$

which is not the same as $M=\mathrm{E}\left[XX^T\right]$.

However, this can be written as the Hadamard product $W \circ M$, where $W$ is a known set of weights.

When I apply the method, I can find a square root of $W \circ M$ that decorrelates the dataset $X$. However, the decorrelated dataset does not have unit variance - the varaince is lower because of the effect of $W$.  However, after doing this for around 100 different datasets, the required correction factor is 0.75, or thereabouts.

Is there a way to derive this correction factor directly from the matrix algebra?

Many thanks in advance.  Just for the record, this question is not being asked in order to  answer to any test or assignment.

Comment: Is your time series a stationary process?

Comment: Yes @dmcdougall, it is a stationary process.

Comment: It is unclear whether $X$ consists of data or is a theoretical construct. If it's a construct, you shouldn't run into this problem. Otherwise, we're talking about *estimates* in place of true expectations and this raises the question of what estimators you are using for the $\gamma(i)$. Any solution would have to depend on your estimation procedure.

Comment: @whuber $X$ is real data and the $\gamma\left(i\right)$ are estimates, such that the leading diagonal of $W$ is 1/n and the other diagonals are symmetric and $\frac{1}{n-k}$, for the kth diagonal, up to $n-1$ where $n$ is the total number of points. I know this is an artefact of the estimation procedure - I am just struggling to find a way to determine a general form for the required correction factor due to the use of estimators.

Comment: I have a question.  Are you trying to remove the dependence between $X(t_i)$ and $X(t_{i+1})$, or are you trying to scale the whole stochastic process such that the stationary distribution is $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$?

Comment: @dmcdougall I am trying to remove the dependence.

Comment: I'd like to help some more.  Do you have some example data I can play with?  Scalar data would be most helpful.